# Combining ListLinePlot with Animation

Tags: plotting, animation

I am quite new to coding world... I am struggling with combining ListLinePlot with Animation, so that it is visible how circle is moving on the path. Here is my code

```
L1 = ListLinePlot[Koordi[[1, 1]]]
p = Animate[
Graphics[{Circle[{x, Koordi[[1, 1, x]]}, 0.5]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {80, 115}}], {x, 0, 110}, 
AnimationRunning -> False];
Show[L1, p]
```

Where as the Koordi are some coordinate points. Like this:

```
{93.3809, 93.6573, 93.934, 94.2112, 94.4893, 94.7684, 95.0488,
95.3308, 95.6148, 95.9008, 96.1892, 96.4803, 96.7744, 97.0715,
97.3718, 97.6755, 97.9827, 98.2935, 98.608, 98.9264, 99.2489,
99.5756, 99.9066, 100.242, 100.582, 100.927, 101.276, 101.631,
101.991, 102.356, 102.726, 103.102, 103.484, 103.872, 104.265, 104.665}
```

[image: Mathematica output]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Without a full definition of `Koordi`, this is going to be difficult to debug completely, but some points: 1. You cannot combine the plot `L1` and the animation `p` with `Show`. You're going to have to wrap animate on the outside of `Show` rather than inside. 2: In `Koordi[[1, 1, x]]`, `x` should be an integer running between 1 and the length of the list `Koordi[[1, 1]]`. Your animation makes `x` a float running from 0, so this can never work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I wrapped the animation on the outside of Show and fixed the interval for x. Now it is working.